# Error campo password requerido Django - Vue

Tags: python-3.x, django, vue.js, axios, djangorestframework

Tengo una API con Django REST framework como Backend y Vuejs como Frontend

Tengo un formulario de usuario que incluyen dos campos de password que me están arrojando un error.

El formulario es el siguiente:

```
                       <form @submit="onSubmit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="first_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nombre</labeL>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="first_name" class="form-control" v-model.trim="form.first_name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="last_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Apellido</labeL>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Apellido" name="last_name" class="form-control" v-model.trim="form.last_name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Usuario</labeL>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" name="username" class="form-control" v-model.trim="form.username">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</labeL>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" class="form-control" v-model.trim="form.email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="user_image" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Imagen de Perfil</labeL>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="file" placeholder="Imagen de Perfil" name="user_image" class="form-control" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password1" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Contraseña</labeL>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="password1" class="form-control" v-model.trim="form.password1">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password2" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Vuelva a escribir la Contraseña</labeL>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Vuelva a escribir la Contraseña" name="password2" class="form-control" v-model.trim="form.password2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="is_active" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Activo</labeL>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="is_active" v-model.trim="form.is_active">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="is_staff" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Usuario Staff</labeL>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="is_staff" v-model.trim="form.is_staff">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="rows">
                            <div class="col text-left">
                                <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Aceptar</b-button>
                                <b-button class="btn-large-space" :to="{name: 'ListUser'}">Cancelar</b-button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Cuando intento editar los datos del usuario, al darle el botón Submit, veo que por la consola del navegador me llega el siguiente mensaje:

```
password: ["Este campo es requerido."]
```

Sin embargo ambos campos de password sí los estoy ingresando, adjunto la captura:

[image: Campo password con datos y el error]

Que puede estar pasando??

Estoy usando axios y el método es PUT para editar el usuario, el código del vue para editar el usuario es el siguiente:

```
    import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      user_id: this.$route.params.user_id,
      form: {
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        username: '',
        email: '',
        user_image: '',
        password1: '',
        password2: '',
        is_active: '',
        is_staff: ''
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {



    onSubmit (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault()
      const path = `http://localhost:8000/core/ListUser/${this.user_id}/`
      axios.put(path, this.form).then((response) => {
        this.form.first_name = response.data.first_name
        this.form.last_name = response.data.last_name
        this.form.username = response.data.username
        this.form.email = response.data.email
        this.form.user_image = response.data.user_image
        this.form.password1 = response.data.password1
        this.form.password2 = response.data.password2
        this.form.is_active = response.data.is_active
        this.form.is_staff = response.data.is_staff
        alert('Usuario Actualizado')
      })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESUELTO:

Utilizando validaciones con vee-validate definí validaciones a cada campo incluyendo los de password

[vee-validate Reglas disponibles](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#rules)